# Using m.me links with ref param

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to deeplink users into my facebook messenger bot, and I need to pass some data in at the same time. Supposedly this can be done by using [m.me links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links), along with a query param.

My bot's page is https://www.facebook.com/Willy-1610141399078870/

The m.me url would be something like this. https://m.me/Willy-1610141399078870?ref=somedatagoeshere

The m.me link works to a degree on desktop, but the data isn't passed to the bot. I don't particularly need it to work on desktop.

However, when I try to open that link on ios or android, I get an error message.

**Android**

> This user name doesn't exist. Try another code or link

**iOS**

> Username was not found

The bot hasn't been published yet, so it won't be visible to anyone else. I need to be able to test this functionality before I publish, so I hope that's not what is causing the failure.

Has anyone else been able to use this feature?

Comment: Are you opening the link with a FB user that is has the admin, developer, or tester role for the associated app?

Comment: I've tried on my admin account, and on a tester account. The bot was created through the test drive button, so I think it may have done something odd. I might try to create a totally new one to see if that solves it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the facebook-generated username can't be used for m.me links. It requires you to register an explicit username.

My page's generated name was Willy-1610141399078870, so https://m.me/Willy-1610141399078870 wasn't a valid url.

To register a username for your page, go to your page > About > Create Page @username.

[image: Create a username]

Then, you can attempt to pick a username that isn't already taken. Somehow, @willy-the-test-page is already taken (?), so I got this incredibly confusing error message:

[image: This page isn't allowed to have a username]

Taking the error message at face value, I decided to create another page and try again. This time, realizing that the message didn't mean what it said. Picking an available username clears the error message, and allows registration.

[image: username registration]

Just kidding! It will tell you again that the page isn't eligible.

[image: actually, no]

---

**The solution was to create a totally new page**, and go through the @username creation flow again. It worked for me on the second attempt.

It's rumored that a page needs at [least 25 likes](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=578164485689750) to become eligible for an @username, but this isn't true in all cases.

Comment: Pretty sure just https://m.me/1610141399078870 would have worked fine ... You need to either use the page user name, or the page id - not a combination of both.

Comment: As CBroe said, none of the above is necessary. The id would have worked just fine.